# Autosuggestion is not working properly using logic in reactJs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, search, logic

I am working on an API search functionality, for this I am using json-server api. Now, problem is, on implementing the autosuggestion functionality to it , by my own logic.
I am facing following problems.

Here's my sandBox. - https://codesandbox.io/s/dark-field-hcpih8?file=/src/App.tsx

1. Auto suggestion box is visible even if I havent typed anything into the search bar.
2. Once, I get the suggested term by clicking on it, it gets added to the search field, that's fine, but after that, my suggestion box should remove everything and disappear, but it is still showing that matched term, and now I am having 1 term into search bar and 1 term into div (for autosuggestion ).
3. I am building front-End of a project, so I need suggestion, is this technique suffice for an enterprise level application's front-end?
4. Is there any NPM package that offers autosuggestion utility out of the box?

Comment: You can add another property flag to show the suggestion box. Mark it as true on input and mark it as false on click of a suggestion.

Comment: Hello dork, I modified the sandbox, but, I want to know how could I impliment an error message when none of the search results matches, because on settting the error will undergo re render as items.length is huge. Could you please suggest something? please tell me if I could implement this functionality into the large application? Please re check my sandbox for changes thus applied by me

Comment: You can make the suggestion list into its own component. In that component, you can just pass the list of suggestions. If there are suggestions, render the list. Otherwise, render the error message.